# Why I am not able to use JNDI DataSource in Tomcat 8?

Tags: tomcat, jndi

I am in a situation, Its been more then two days, but could not get the database connectivity using JNDI.

I am getting the below error

> org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance
>   Name = myDatabase Ignoring unknown property: value of "My DataSource new" for "description" property

I am using `Tomcat-8` `Java-1.8`, `Spring-3` and `Maven 3.2.5`.

I am trying to deploy my web app in Tomcat. I have created war and placed in TOMCAT/webapp directory.

**Tomcat/conf/server.xml file configuration for Database**

```
server.xml

<GlobalNamingResources>

<Resource name="jdbc/myDatabase"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
              driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
             url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@IpAddress:orcl"
              username="tomcat_dbrds"
              password="cmxinfa"
              initialSize="1"
              minIdle="1"
              maxIdle="1"
              maxActive="3"
              maxWait="1000"
              validationQuery="select 1 from dual"
              jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.SlowQueryReport(threshold=1500)"
            />
  </GlobalNamingResources>
```

**Spring Application context content**

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="monitoringDataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/myDatabase" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

**web.xml** content

```
  <resource-ref>
    <description>My DataSource new</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/myDatabase</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
```

What am I missing?

I have tried all possible configuration but nothing worked.

```
<Resource name="myDatabase" 
              global="monitords"
              factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              username="tomcat_dbrds"
              password="cmxinfa"
              driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
              url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@myipaddress:1521:orcl"
              initialSize="20"
              maxWaitMillis="15000"
              maxTotal="100"
              maxIdle="20"
              defaultAutoCommit="true"
              />


<Resource name="jdbc/myDatabase"
          auth="Container"
          factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              validationQuery="SELECT 1"
              validationInterval="30000"
              timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
              maxActive="20"
              maxIdle="10"
              minIdle="1"
              maxWait="20000"
              initialSize="20"
              removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
          removeAbandoned="true"
              logAbandoned="true"
              minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000"
              jmxEnabled="true"
              jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer"
              username="tomcat_dbrds"
              password="cmxinfa"
              driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
              url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@myipaddress:1521:orcl"/>




<Resource name="jdbc/myDatabase"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
              driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
             url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@myipaddress:1521:orcl"
              username="tomcat_dbrds"
              password="cmxinfa"
              initialSize="1"
              minIdle="1"
              maxIdle="1"
              maxActive="3"
              maxWait="1000"
              validationQuery="select 1 from dual"
              jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.SlowQueryReport(threshold=1500)"
            />
```

**Update 1 :**

I have removed the description tag from `web.xml` but still I am getting the same error. I just checked the server log and actual error is below.
How do I solve this error.

> java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for
>   connect URL 'null'

**Update 2:**

**stack trace**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:382)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:456)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:464)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForList(JdbcTemplate.java:497)
    at com.globalss.dnb.monitor.dao.ApplicationConfig.<init>(ApplicationConfig.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2160)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2032)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1532)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.acceptsURL(OracleDriver.java:620)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:299)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2144)
    ... 57 more
```

Comment: Strange, indeed. Tried already to delete the description property from web.xml?

Comment: @LittleSanti I have delete the description property from `web.xml` still the same error in console. but in server log i see the bellow error `java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'/`

Comment: Are you sure this is the only <Resource> declared in your server.xml?

Comment: I see one suspicious line: driverClassName should be `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` (tough I don't believe this will cause the error, actually).

Comment: @LittleSanti Yes I m sure I have  only <Resource> declared in my server.xml

Comment: could the problem be in the jdbc library??? This must be installed in a directory accesible by tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

tomcat_dir\conf\context.xml - worked.  Using eclipse-tomcat env.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) helps to improve the quality of your response. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Put your resource definition between context tag in `tomcat_dir\conf\context.xml`.

[image: tomcat context configuration file]